# WiX util:user LogonAsService failed to read attributes

Tags: wix, burn

I am getting an error message when running the WiX installer in console mode. It works in normal mode. The error log says

> CreateUser:  Error 0x80070103: failed to read attributes from custom action data
>   CustomAction CreateUser returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

After reading up on it appears to be something with the security of the properties Name / Account. I've tried setting the [ACCOUNT] and [PASSWORD] property to Secure="yes" but it didnt work
The log files says and the same error message:

> Property(S): AdminProperties = ACCOUNT;PASSWORD
>   Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = ACCOUNT;NETFRAMEWORK45;PASSWORD;WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED

The command line looks something like this

```
C:\build\console\setup.exe -passive /Account mydomain\myuser /Password mypassword /Verify
```

and wix code that fails

```
<util:User Id="GrantUserLogOnAsService" UpdateIfExists="no" FailIfExists="no" RemoveOnUninstall ="no" CreateUser="no" LogonAsService="yes"
                       Name="[ACCOUNT]"/>
```

I also tried to hardcode it and it does succeed...

```
<util:User Id="GrantUserLogOnAsService" UpdateIfExists="no" FailIfExists="no" RemoveOnUninstall ="no" CreateUser="no" LogonAsService="yes"
                           Name="mydomain/myuser" />
```

I would be happy if I could just catch the error and ignore it, however the util:user does not have a vital="no" attribute. Thanks for any help on this.

The mystery is why the properties cannot be read, when [Account] = mydomain/myuser. I've verified this by looking at the logs.

Can I resolve the [ACCOUNT] property to a normal string before i pass it to util:User? since it seems to fail at resolving it inside.

Comment: I think I'm having this same issue.  You ever figure out what the problem/resolution was?

Comment: no we moved on to creating custom actions instead, (they can be unittested). These wix tools are too confusing sometimes.